# Website won't go responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Hello i'm haveing a issue with my website, it won't go responsive. I'm using bootstrap but it's not scaling down. I am using this code in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But it still won't scale down...

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This worked for me

Comment: Also you need to include  html5shiv.js  And  respond.min.js